# Windows 7 desktop icons randomly

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons

After reboots, my Windows 7 desktop icons will randomly change size.

I am referring to the icons with a gray border around them. A search has not yielded me a working resolution. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: Are those... My little ponies over all your icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many things can cause this, from desktop settings to a corrupt user profile.

Things to try.

1.) Right click on the desktop and select View, be sure "auto arrange icons" is Not selected.Right click again to view settings and un-select "align to grid"

2.) [Some suggest software](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/save-and-restore-desktop-icon-layout-in-windows-vista/) to sort it out in some cases

3.) [Try rebuilding the icon cache](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html#post463743)

4.) Create a new user account, then [copy the old user account settings to the new account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Fix-a-corrupted-user-profile)